# Run controller action or rest api and display results in yii2

Tags: rest, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a controller action / rest api that returns a json data

**/user/1**

```
{
    "name" : "Paul",
    "surname" : "Phoenix",
    "age" : "20",
    "status" : "active",
}
```

But i need to use this data some places in my yii application. For example, i have a component that do some stuff with user data then returns a formatted result. How do i call this api in my component so i can use it? Or how do i display this data directly on a view.

Do i need to use `file_get_contents(Url::to(['/user/view', 'id' => 1], true)`?
Which will do:
`file_get_contents(http://localhost/user/1)`

Then use this data wherever i need? Or are there any easier solution to use api data within the framework?

Comment: use `json_decode($data);` then you have array of data.

Comment: you didn't understand the question... i asked how do i get the data? How do i call the api from anywhere in my application without having to use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to run an action from a controller you simply do `$this->runAction('actionid')`, but what if i need to run this action somewhere else?

Comment: you can use postman for that.

Comment: well, if you are within the application you don't need to call the api for it. just do `$user = User::findOne($user_id_here);` in your component and it will return you `user` object. then you can do other stuff with it. @user2707590